# Using user script functions within Android app

Tags: javascript, android, html, userscripts

I have a HTML document that I'd like to convert into an Android app.

I use the HTML document currently through Chrome/Firefox on my PC. I also have a Greasemonkey User script that alters the functionality/behaviour of the web page.

What I need to know is, is it possible to package the features of the user script and the HTML document into an Android app?

For example, the app interface would be the HTML document, possibly with a drop down menu that lists the functions of the user script and gives you the ability to perform these functions?

Is this possible, if so, what do I need to look at to make it possible.

Thanks